# Remove specific files from iCloud

Tags: macos, icloud, finder, desktop

I was just wondering how I can remove certain big folders from my iCloud Drive and have it only save on my Mac. I've got some folders filled with footage that's like 800gb that I don't need taking up iCloud space, but still need it saved on my desktop. appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: Folders are easy but you mention footage - what app are they stored with?

Comment: They are just in finder, in a photo on my “desktop.”

Comment: What do you mean by in a photo?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly you have turned on `Desktop & Document Folders` in the iCloud Drive Options but want to exclude a certain folder on the Desktop from syncing to iCloud?

The easiest way would probably be to move the folder somewhere else that is not the Desktop or Documents folder.

Or you can add/change the filename to stop it from syncing like described here:

[How to exclude a sub folder from iCloud drive in macOS Sierra?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/254313/how-to-exclude-a-sub-folder-from-icloud-drive-in-macos-sierra)

Answer (score 0):

Right-click the folder or files and select "Remove Download." They may re-download in the future but it will clear the space in the short-term.